# Where does Ecto.Migrations pull the list of migrations?

Tags: elixir, ecto, elixir-mix

where does Mix retrieve the migrations when I issue the command `mix ecto.migrations`?

I thought it would refer to the list of migration files under `priv/repo/migrations`, but it seems to remember the old migrations that had been deleted from that folder.

Since I'm re-using the migration files from another project (and deleted some of the irrelevant migration files), the database has no tables (including the one that Ecto uses to record the migration history)

Comment: I ran into a similar issue recently. I assume they got compiled because running `MIX_ENV=test mix clean` then the migrations fixed my issue.

Comment: Justin, what would be the Windows equivalent of that? Set Mix_Env=test mix clean? I went ahead and tried it. When I ran `mix ecto.migrations` after with that setting, I got `could not load config config/test mix clean.exs`.

Comment: How are you entering this command? Windows command prompt or something like cygwin?

Comment: WIndows command prompt

Comment: Looking through the Elixir [getting started](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html#environments) section for mix. There is a part at the bottom of the environments section showing how to do things on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Ecto creates additional table in your DB named `schema_migrations` that contains list of applied migrations and date and time when it was applied.